# Updating reference value mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, reference

My localbodyname schema has

```
 dist_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"districts",
      },

 localbody_company:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"tbl_company"
    }
```

I am trying to update with a formdata.my req.body has
`district_name` and `company_name`. How can I update `dist_id` and `localbody_company` with this?

I tried doing this, but it's not working:

```
updateLocalbody = (req) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let company = await models.Company.findOne({
        company_name: req.body.localbody_company.company_name
      });
      //console.log(company)
      req.body.localbody_company = company._id;
      let district = await models.District.findOne({
        district_name: req.body.dist_id.district_name
      });
      req.body.dist_id = district._id;

      let localbody = await models.LocalbodyName.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.localbody_Id,
        req.body,
        {
          new: true
        }
      );
      resolve(localbody);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject({
        message: err.message
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Is there required value returned in the ```company``` and ```district``` variables?

Comment: yes.when i console.log(req.body) its showing the crresponding dist_id and company__id.

Comment: thanks @fractal397. the id was returning wrong.i got it ..  district_name:req.body.dist_id.district_name ws wrong. i just need to mention req.body.district_name